# How to remove the assembly info from this string?

Tags: c#

I have the following code. It returns the assembly information because it is a [closed generic type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1).

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
t = list.GetType();
Console.WriteLine(t.FullName);
```

Prints the following:

```
//System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib,
//Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

I know I can write logic that splits between "[[" and "]]" to remove the properties such as version, culture, and publickeytoken. I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to remove those properties?

Edit:
The output I want is

```
//System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib]], mscorlib
```

Comment: You can always just build the name from scratch using `FullName`,`Namespace` and the results of `GetGenericArguments()`, assuming that type `IsGenericType`. The only issue - `FullName` needs some more parsing to remove/replace the suffix `N. IMO is better to build from parts than deconstruct from already built.

Comment: Could you post an example as an answer? I'll accept it.

Comment: and what do you mean by the suffix N?

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit of mental abbreviation. Generic types contain suffix \`N in the name, where N is the number of generic arguments. `FullName` for open generic types ends with this suffix, while closed generic types also include the generic arguments - as you posted in the question. That can be also worked around by using `Name` and `Namespace`, it all depends on the desired result.

Comment: @RufusL Please see my edit.

Comment: FYI, you can get the inner type by doing `t.GetMethod("get_Item").ReturnType.FullName`, And you can get the assembly name using `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(t.GetMethod("get_Item").ReturnType.Assembly.CodeBase)`. In this way, you can build up the parts you need.

Comment: @RufusL thanks for the answer. What if there are n layers of inner types?

Comment: @RufusL, what's wrong with `.GetGenericArguments()` and `.Assembly.GetName().Name`? @user3587180 - put your name generation in a method and call it recursively. I highly doubt you would run out of stack.

Comment: @RufusL, of course it did, https://dotnetfiddle.net/0H4r4J, what else did you expect?

Comment: @kiziu the issue I see with your fiddle is that you are assuming there is only one generic type argument. For my project there could be none, one, or many.

Comment: @user3587180, that fiddle is for Rufus' comment. Obviously you have to check for generic type and all possible generic arguments, which I described in my first comment. I think this discussion is far too long for comments and should be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
internal class Program {

    public static void Main(string[] args) {

        List<String> list = new List<String>();
        Type t = list.GetType();

        string yourString = string.Format(
                                          "{0}.{1}.[[{2}, {3}]], {3}",
                                          t.Namespace,
                                          t.Name,
                                          t.GetGenericArguments()[0],
                                          t.Assembly.GetName().Name);

        Console.WriteLine(yourString);

        // This prints :
        //System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib]], mscorlib
    }

}
```